# What does <tx:annotation-driven/> in Spring really do in the code level?

Tags: spring

Does it set a flag in a bean ?
Does it load "special" bean which then looks for `@Transactional` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It scans all beans in the application context and creates [AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction) interceptor for those which are annotated.

This is done via the `SpringTransactionAnnotationParser`, which is used by [`TransactionInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html) - the aformentioned interceptor.

Then whenever these beans are accessed, this advice is triggered and a transaction is started before the target method is executed, and committed after the execution.